# Newly installed CentOS 6 shows squares instead of letters

Tags: centos, nx

I have a VPS which I've just reinstalled an OS on. The OS is CentOS 6 x32.

I've exactly done the following:

```
yum install wget nano firefox
yum update
yum groupinstall Desktop

useradd wajed && passwd wajed
visudo

yum install nx freenx 
nxserver --adduser wajed
cat /etc/passwd | grep ^nx
cat /var/lib/nxserver/home/.ssh/client.id_dsa.key
```

So,

1. I installed some software, updated the OS, installed Desktop.
2. Added a user and gave permissions.
3. Installed freenx.

The result is that everything is good, and I could connect to the desktop, but there is no font... it's all boxes instead of letters. What could the problem be?

Here is a screenshot: [image]

Answer (score 2):

This has to be a fonts problem.

This is from one [forum reference](https://www.centos.org/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?topic_id=33144):

```
yum install xorg-x11-fonts-Type1
```